# What is the equivalent component of react-helmet in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-helmet

Please do anyone know how to replace react-helmet (in React.js) to a similar component in react-native?

Here is the official page of react-helmet:

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet